# Windows Backup Using Powershell

Tags: windows, backup, powershell

I wrote the following Powershell Script to perform a one time backup of my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The idea is to perform a Weekly backup to a different external drive and schedule the script to run from Task Scheduler.

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-PSSnapin Windows.ServerBackup

$backup = Get-WBPolicy
$weekly = New-WBPolicy

Add-WBVolume -POLICY $weekly -VOLUME $backup.VolumesToBackup

$inc1 = NEW-WBFileSpec -FileSpec "C:\"
$inc2 = NEW-WBFileSpec -FileSpec "D:\"
$incs = $inc1,$inc2
Add-WBFileSpec -POLICY $weekly -fileSpec $incs

$disk = WBDisk | where{$_.DiskName -EQ "Seagate Backup+ Desk USB Device"}
$target = New-WBBackupTarget -DISK $disk
Add-WBBackupTarget -POLICY $weekly -TARGET $target

Add-WBBareMetalRecovery -POLICY $weekly
Set-WBVSSBackupOptions -POLICY $weekly -VSSFULLBACKUP

Start-WBBackup -POLICY $weekly
```

I get the following error:

```
Start-WBBackup : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\Users\ejb\Documents\Scripts\WeeklyBackup.ps1:21 char:15
+ Start-WBBackup <<<<  -POLICY $weekly
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-WBBackup], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Windows.ServerBackup.Commands.StartWBBackup
```

I checked and verified that all the proper modules, snapins and features were installed/loaded.

Comment: If you debug it, what's the state of $weekly object when you get to (just before) the Start-WBBackup line (21)?  It seems to be saying it's NULL. If it's not NULL are all (required) properties set as expected in that object?

Comment: Yes. I placed a breakpoint in the ISE before the Start command is executed and $weekly variable has this value:

`Schedule            : 
BackupTargets       : {Seagate Backup+ Desk USB Device}
VolumesToBackup     : {DATAPART1 (D:), Local disk (C:)}
FilesSpecsToBackup  : {C:\*, D:\*}
FilesSpecsToExclude : {}
BMR                 : True
SystemState         : False
VssBackupOptions    : VssFullBackup`

I checked MSDN and schedule does not need to be set for this case.

Comment: Can you Start-WBBackup manually?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem was being caused by the way I was setting the target. Even though it was showing correctly set, it was not bound correctly to the WBPolicy I was making. The correct way to set the target was:

```
$disk = New-WBBackupTarget -VolumePath G:
Add-WBBackupTarget -POLICY $backup -TARGET $disk
```

Although this assumes that the disk attached is always mounted to the G: letter, it worked successfully when I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem when defining onetime backup (or generating Policy on-the-fly). I think... You have to use Volume (object from Get-WBVolume) or VolumePath (if mount letter is available). Disk options is there when you want to define persistent policy. When you use Disk (object from Get-WBDisk), you have to use Set-Policy and disk will be cleared and new volume will be created on it. That volume will be then used.